# Vue.js - How to use v-for in JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I have JSON output from server:

```
[
    {"id":"2","name":"Peter","age":"24"}, 
    {"id":"4","name":"Lucy","age":"18"},
]
```

and now I want to use it with `v-for` directive, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my export default:

```
data () {
    return {
        info: {}
    }
},

mounted () {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:4000/fetch.php/')
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
},
```

And now if I want to display output of info, it works well `{{ info }}`.

But I need to use `v-for` directive and display only names.

```
<p v-if="info.name">{{ info.name }}</p>
```

But it is not working, only what is working is this: `{{ info[0].name }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read the `name` property directly like this: `info.name`. Since the output is an array of objects rather than a single object.

```js
data () {
    return {
        info: [], // make this an empty array
    }
},
mounted () {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:4000/fetch.php/')
        .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
},
```

Then, you can render the `info` array in your template using `v-for` directive:

```
<ul v-if="info.length">
    <li v-for="item in info" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Read more about [List Rendering in Vue](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html).